# Linear algebra based proof that if there exists $P\succ 0$ and $P\succ A^TPA$ then $|\lambda_i(A)|<1$

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, control-theory, lyapunov-functions

Is there a proof based on linear algebra that shows the following?

> If there exist $P \succ 0$ and $P \succ A^TPA$, then $| \lambda_i (A) | < 1$ for all $i$.

Here, $|\lambda_i(A)|$ denotes the magnitude of the $i$th eigenvalue, which may be complex.

Unless I've made a mistake, this is simply a Lyapunov stability condition for the discrete-time linear time-invariant system $x_{k+1} = Ax_k$.  That said, the original statement above contains no statement about stability and is simply a statement about the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$.  As such, it seems like there should be a direct proof, but I've not seen one and am not sure how to derive it.

Comment: What is your definition of  "magnitude"? Because both because of the name and also because of your notation it would seem that magnitude must be a non-negative real number...

Comment: I guess it should be $|\lambda_i(A)| < 1$.

Comment: @SampleTime You're correct.  Fixed.

Comment: @DonAntonio I made a mistake on the bound.  Magnitude means the magnitude of the complex eigenvalue.  This didn't really make any sense when the bound was 0, which was a mistake.  Hopefully, it makes more sense now with the bound of 1.

Comment: What's $\prec$ mean here?

Comment: @wyer33 The mistake still seems to be there...

Comment: @DonAntonio Oof.  Three places to fix and I fixed only two.  Hopefully, this is correct now.

Comment: @chhro In this context it means positive definite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As another user has pointed out in a comment, the correct statement should be: if $P\succ0$ and $P\succ A^TPA$, then $|\lambda_i(A)|<1$ for each $i$, i.e. $\rho(A)<1$.

The proof is simple. As $P$ is positive definite, it has a (unique) positive definite square root $P^{1/2}$. Multiply by $P^{-1/2}$ on both sides of $P\succ A^TPA$, we get $I\succ B^TB$, where $B=P^{1/2}AP^{-1/2}$. It follows that $\rho(A)^2=\rho(B)^2\le\|B\|^2=\rho(B^TB)<1$ where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the operator norm.